# Change rows into columns inside the loop? Plot printed data?

Tags: python, loops, plot

I have a big problem to with plotting in python. I have to plot the following variable from the loop.

for i in range(0,n-1):

```
currentEficciency=((Cd[i]*Qd[i]-Cd[i+1]*Qd[i+1])*F)/(iy[i]*A/n)

print(currentEficciency)
```

How to plot those data? It prints n rows with values. I want to plot 1 row with n columns. How can do this?

It prints this:

1.0044399334976073

1.00229274924689

1.0001246790898541

0.9979513624285106

0.9957603086990192

0.9935547775459884

0.7323664112555096

Hot can I plot those values?

Answer (score 0):

Write your output to a string and print it:

```
output = ''
for i in range(0,n-1):
    currentEficciency=((Cd[i]*Qd[i]-Cd[i+1]*Qd[i+1])*F)/(iy[i]*A/n)
    output += currentEficciency + ' '
print(output)
```

Comment: in what sense does it not work? what is the error message that you receive?